# Difference between two lmer model

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

Can you please explain where is the difference between the following two models :

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject) + (0+Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

I noticed there is some discrepency in the estimate for random effect between model fm1 and fm2 . But don't know why ?

```
summary(fm1)$varcor
Groups   Name        Std.Dev. Corr 
Subject  (Intercept) 24.7404       
          Days         5.9221  0.066
Residual             25.5918       


summary(fm2)$varcor
Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
Subject   (Intercept) 25.0513 
Subject.1 Days         5.9882 
Residual              25.5653
```

And the fixed effect estimates are same for the both model .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second model includes random intercepts and slopes, under the assumption that the correlation between them is 0. The first model also estimates that correlation and thus has one more parameter.

Comment: +1 -- but don't you mean to say one more *parameter* and therefore one *less* degree of freedom?

Comment: @Pavel But I see both have same number of parameter , in first model `(Intercept)` and `Days` also , in the second model `(Intercept)` and `Subject.1 Days` , though I don't understand what is meant by `Subject.1 ` ?

Comment: And how is to see the *degrees of freedom?*

Comment: @Munira: But there is an additional parameter in the first model which is the correlation. It's in the right-most column (0.066, in your example). "Subject.1" is just a minor technicallity - it's R's way of dealing with two rows with the same name.

Comment: @Munira: Degrees of freedom appear to be a problematic issue when you model random effects: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html